# Is there anyway to show the iterated integral of $\frac{e^{238\alpha}e^{471283\beta}}{e^{e^{\alpha + 1976\beta}}}$ is finite?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am currently trying to show that a probability density function I have is finite, given the data. My explicit function looks like the following:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{238\alpha}e^{471283\beta}}{e^{e^{\alpha + 1976\beta}}}d\alpha d\beta
$$

Is there any easy way to show that this integral is finite? (or perhaps divergent if not so)? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way :) Did you tried to simplify the integrand?